# OnTriggerEnter2D working only when the game starts, i want it to check for collisions every frame

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game in unity, a type of sliding number puzzle where you have to line up each piece in ascending order. My code of checking collisions is only working when I start the game, so if I move a piece, it won't tell the near pieces that I moved the near piece. I hope you understood my problem, every help is appreciated. Thank you.
This is how my code looks with the up check. I

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{

    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Piece" || collision.gameObject.name == "Up_Collider")

    {
        piece_Script.Collide_Up = true;
        Debug.LogError("Up");

    }
    else
    {
        piece_Script.Collide_Up = false;
    }
    
}
```

I Thought that the else statement will solve this problem but it didn't.

Comment: Can you show a picture of your scene, so we get an idea of how these shapes are moving relative to each other? It'd be nice if you could describe the expected behaviour when something moves from one place to another.

Comment: I'm gonna send a youtube link with my problem

Comment: Here: https://youtu.be/oYSlR2Gtoro

Comment: It would be ideal if you included your movement code in your question - that's also relevant. But I'll try to answer it based on what you've included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code in your question and your video, I see at least a couple issues.

**First, there's an issue with how you're moving pieces.** Your movement code for a Piece is:

```cs
Piece.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(a, b, t);
```

This is not correct if you want to trigger collider events. These require interactions with rigidbodies, which means you should instead be changing the position of the piece's rigidbody with [Rigidbody2D.MovePosition()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html). This will move your rigidbody within the physics system, which means taking into account collisions/triggers.

So (assuming you get the rigidbody for each Piece when you initialize them), your code might look like:

```cs
// Note also that I used Vector2 here - it's best you keep it consistent
pieceRigidbody.MovePosition(Vector2.Lerp(a, b, t));
```

**Second, OnTriggerEnter2D() is not fired when two colliders stop touching.** So I don't see your "else" condition being particularly useful. To achieve that with your current code, you could theoretically introduce `OnTriggerExit2D()` to take care of the "else" condition. However, you run into complications because while moving, a Piece may Enter and Exit the same directional colliders of two other Pieces before coming to rest. You'd have to take into account the order that occurs to get an accurate final state.

While workable, I have an alternative approach to suggest: Abandon using Trigger Collider events, and only check for a valid move at the time a Piece is clicked. Eliminate the collider event handlers, and just execute a [Physics2D.OverlapBox()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapBox.html) in each position around a Piece when it is clicked. If the position is occupied by another piece or an edge, that's not a valid move. If there is a position without something blocking it, then move the piece there.

In terms of how you'd implement that, here's an approach that handles basic scenarios:

```cs
// This would be called when a tile is clicked, to figure out where
// you can move it (if anywhere)
Vector2 GetValidMove(Vector2 tilePosition, Vector2 tileSize)
{
    // Check in four directions around the supplied tile position
    Vector2 possiblePosition = tilePosition + Vector2.up * tileSize.y;
    if (IsPositionEmpty(possiblePosition, tileSize)){
        return possiblePosition;
    }
    possiblePosition = tilePosition + Vector2.down * tileSize.y;
    if (IsPositionEmpty(possiblePosition, tileSize)){
        return possiblePosition;
    }
    possiblePosition = tilePosition + Vector2.right * tileSize.x;
    if (IsPositionEmpty(possiblePosition, tileSize)){
        return possiblePosition;
    }
    possiblePosition = tilePosition + Vector2.left * tileSize.x;
    if (IsPositionEmpty(possiblePosition, tileSize)){
        return possiblePosition;
    }

    // If no direction is free, then there is no valid move
    return Vector2.zero;
}

bool IsPositionEmpty(Vector2 checkedPosition, Vector2 tileSize)
{
    // Check an area just slightly smaller than a tile, so we don't risk
    // detecting the originating tile
    Vector2 checkSize = tileSize * 0.95f;
    Collider2D collider = Physics2D.OverlapBox(checkedPosition, checkSize, 0);

    // If no collider is found, the position should be empty
    // This assume your sides and tiles all have colliders
    return collider == null;
}
```

Comment: Can you show me an example of how I need to write the Phisics2D.OverlapBox() code because I have no idea on how to do it. Thank you

Comment: @AraAraSayonnara Sure, I've added an idea for how you might approach checking for valid moves when a tile is clicked. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: In this case, how can I get the tileScale as a Vector2 ? I tried everything but found only Vectors 3

Comment: @AraAraSayonnara In Unity, you can actually use Vector2 and Vector3 interchangeably. Using a Vector3 where a Vector2 is expected would just drop the z value, but if your game is 2D then the z value for scale has no real value.

Comment: So just to be clear, in this case I would use GetValidMove(new Vector2(transform.position.x,transform.position.y), transform.localScale.magnitude); I don't think it looks right..

Comment: Oh, no, I see what you mean. I've updated the answer to accept a Vector2 now, and it uses the x/y components to determine how far over to check for an empty space.

Comment: This makes so much sense now, thank you again and I'm sorry if I disturbed. Have a nice day!

Comment: Of course! I'm glad this has at least given you a different perspective on the problem. If this does solve your question, you can click the checkmark next to the answer to accept it. That marks the question as answered so others know you don't need further help. (Make sure to check your other questions in case you have answers you want to accept there too!)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the things I write below are correct in your project:

1- You are using **"2D"** colliders on **both** objects.
2- At least **1** of the objects has a **"Rigidbody2D"**.
3- **IsTrigger** Checkbox is active in your collider.
4- You are using the correct **Tag**.
5- Check **layer collision matrix** in - Edit > Project Setting > Physics2D.

And it is better to use tag instead of name

Comment: Can you help me and say what I did wrong ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYSlR2Gtoro&ab_channel=denis55